# how to clear all of datagridview rows including the first row(i have tried Dgv.DataSource = null; Dgv.Rows.Clear();)

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am a beginner of C# and created a DataGridView like:

```
private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn createText(string name, string Hname, int width)
{
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn tmt = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    tmt.Name = name;
    tmt.HeaderText = Hname;
    tmt.Width = width;
    tmt.DataPropertyName = name;
    return tmt;
}

private DataGridViewComboBoxColumn PMcreateCombo(string name, int width, string item_str)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn tmd = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    string[] items;

    items = item_str.Split(' ');
    tmd.HeaderText = name;
    tmd.Name = name;
    //tmd.MaxDropDownItems = 4;
    foreach (string str in items)
    {
        tmd.Items.Add(str);
    }
    tmd.Width = width;
    tmd.DataPropertyName = name;
    return tmd;
}
```

I want to use a numericupdown to control the number of columns, so i wrote something like this:

```
private void numericUD_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dgv.DataSource = null;
    Dgv.Rows.Clear();
    Init();
}
private void Init()
{ 
    SCM = new List<SCM>();
    Dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    Dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

    Dgv.Columns.Add(createText("AA", "AA", 60));
    Dgv.Columns.Add(createCombo("QQ", 60, "RRR GGG BBB"));
    addNewColumns();

    Dgv.DataSource = Table;            
}
```

But when i change the numericUpDown, the AA QQ and Addnewcolumn all are created just after  the old one, but if i mark the `Init()` in the `functionnumericUD_ValueChanged`, the first row (AA QQ) still remains, but the second row disappears.

So i want to ask how to delete all of the element in DataGridView including the first row, then create a new one according to the numericrupdown

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the DataGridView after clearing the datasource.

```
private void numericUD_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dgv.DataSource = null;
    Dgv.refresh();
    Init();
}
```